# Ember.js - ember-pikaday not resolving American dates?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to pass a replacement datepicker on the site with the geb tests we are running.

it is failing on handling an American mock test

```
{{pikaday-input
  value=localisedValue
  format=(if format format "DD/MM/YYYY")
  name=name
  placeholder=localisedPlaceholder
  onSelection=(action setValue)
  id=inputId
  classNames="date-placeholder"
  tabindex=tabIndex
}}
```

date.js

```
import LocalisedTextInput from './localised-text-input';

export default LocalisedTextInput.extend({
  setValue(dateValue) {
    if(dateValue) {
      let valueFormat = this.get('valueFormat') ? this.get('valueFormat') : 'YYYY-MM-DD';

      if(valueFormat !== 'date') {
        dateValue = window.moment(dateValue).format(valueFormat);
      }
      else {
        dateValue = window.moment(dateValue);
      }
    }

    this.set('localisedValue', dateValue);
  }
});
```

and the test

```
def "Agenda Day renders correctly in the US"() {
    given:
        bootstrapPublishedTestEvent()

    and:
        def page = asyncTo EditAgendaPage, siteUnderTest

    when:
        page.mockTimeZone(420)
        page.addDay('20/02/2016', 'Day 1')

    then:

        page.days*.date == ["20/02/2016"]
}
```

when I comment out page.mockTimeZone(420) -- the test passes.

mockTimeZone is using the TimeShift.js lib

```
Date = TimeShift.Date;
TimeShift.setTimezoneOffset(420);
```

---

there is a bug that if the date from the server is 31/12/2019 - in UK timezone it is correct -- but in the US timezone it shows as 30/12/2019

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I resolved it -- had to add - useUTC -- and add it to the momentjs

Comment: Its better to close the question and bounty if it is resolved :)